# uri = data.getData() es null en Jelly bean

Tags: android

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Android Studio y probándola con mi smartphone 4.2.2, necesito en primer lugar tomar una foto y obtener su Uri para luego recortarla. En internet encontré que para eso se utiliza:

```
url = data.getData();
```

Pero de igual manera investigué que en Jelly bean esto no funciona así, y efectivamente porque lo que obtengo como resultado es NULL a pesar de que la foto si la logra capturar. Ya he estado horas intentando de todo pero hasta el momento no encuentro algo que solucione el problema. ¿Existe otra manera de obtener el Uri? Gracias

Anexo el resto del código por si acaso.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_eslyss);
    boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }
    });
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap bitmap2 = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        uri = data.getData();

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(Activity.this, Salto1.class);
        intent.putExtra("Bitmap", bitmap2);
        startActivity(intent);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que agregar [**EXTRA_OUTPUT**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_OUTPUT) a tu Intent `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` donde defines la Uri del archivo temporal:

```
 Uri captureImage = Uri.fromFile(getTempFile());
 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, captureImage);
```

sería de esta forma:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

     Uri captureImage = Uri.fromFile(getTempFile());
     intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, captureImage);

    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

> [EXTRA_OUTPUT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_OUTPUT) El nombre del Intent-extra se utiliza para indicar
>   un Uri de resolución de contenido que se utilizará para almacenar la
>   imagen o el vídeo solicitado.

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente tengas el mismo problema que en [este post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/78158/error-al-obtener-una-imagen-desde-la-c%C3%A1mara-en-android/78164#78164)

Efectivamente, tienes que pasar la `Uri` en el `Intent` que usas para abrir la cámara, pero si lo haces usando `Uri.fromFile()` te dará `android.os.FileUriExposedException` si tienes como `targetSdkVersion = 24`, así que te recomiendo usar [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) para evitarlo.