# Problemas al obtener una imagen desde la cámara en android

Tags: android

Tengo este código para coger imagenes desde la cámara:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
    .setTitle("Seleccionar Imagen")
    .setPositiveButton("Galeria", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Seleccionar Imagen"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_GALLERY);
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cámara", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            tipoImagen = false;
            Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(takePicture, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CAMERA);//zero can be replaced with any action code
        }
    })
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_dialer)
    .show();

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

    }
    else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

    }
}
```

El caso es que si pruebo la app con un `Samsung Galaxy Note III` con la `API 19` funciona correctamente. Pero si la pruebo un `Huawei P8 Lite` con la `API 21` no me coge la imagen.

¿Alguna idea de porque puede ser esto?

Comment: Prueba con el ejemplo de esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8399/c%C3%B3mo-abrir-la-c%C3%A1mara-de-un-tel%C3%A9fono-desde-android/8418#8418

Comment: **¿Que error?**

Comment: Mas que un error, es un problema con algunos dispositivos @Jorgesys

Answer (score 1):

Los `Huawei` son un quebradero de cabeza!

Para empezar, no suelen incluir la `uri` de la foto en en `Intent data` después de hacer la foto.

Lo que puedes hacer(al menos a mi me funciona tanto en `Samsung` como en `Huawei`) es:

1- Crear un `File`:

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), subdir);
File photoFile = new File(dir, filename);
```

2- Obtener la `Uri` del archivo que acabas de crear usando:

```
Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, fileProviderAuthority, photoFile);
```

3- Pasar la `Uri` en el `Intent` que usas para abrir la `cámara`:

```
Intent deviceCameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
deviceCameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
deviceCameraIntent.setClipData(ClipData.newRawUri(null, fileUri));
deviceCameraIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
deviceCameraIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivityForResult(deviceCameraIntent, REQUEST_CODE_DEVICE_CAMERA);
```

(A partir de la `API 23` tienes que otorgarle permisos de lectura/escritura a la `Uri`)

Luego, cuando vuelvas a tu `Activity` la foto debería estar en el `File` que creaste al principio.

Este [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) puedes encontrar más información sobre `FileProvider` y como usarlo correctamente.

**EDITADO**

Las variables no definidas arriba son estas:

- `filename` es simplemente un `String` con el nombre que quieras ponerle a la foto(puedes usar la fecha y hora por ejemplo para que no se repitan, o simplemente `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`.
- `subdir` es otro `String` tipo "img" o "fotos".
- `fileProviderAuthority` uso `com.example.mobileapp.fileprovider` (el nombre del paquete de la app + `.fileprovider`

También tienes que añadir esto al `manifest`:

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
    android:authorities="@string/file_provider_authority" 
    android:exported="false" 
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"> 

    <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" /> 
</provider>
```

Tienes que añadir en el archivo `strings.xml`

```
<string name="file_provider_authority" translatable="false">com.example.app.fileprovider</string>
```

Y por último, crear el archivo `file_paths.xml` en `res/xml/` con el siguiente contenido:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: `filename` es simplemente un `String` con el nombre que quieras ponerle a la foto(puedes usar la fecha y hora por ejemplo para que no se repitan, o simplemente ` UUID.randomUUID().toString()`

`subdir` es otro `String` tipo "img" o "fotos"

y para `fileProviderAuthority` uso `com.example.mobileapp.fileprovider` (el nombre del paquete de la app + `.fileprovider`

Comment: ah! olvidaba que tienes que añadir esto al `AndroidManifest`:


`<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="@string/file_provider_authority"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>`

(echa un vistazo al link que he pasado antes)

Comment: he editado mi comentario anterior ;)

Comment: He editado mi respuesta con los últimos pasos

Comment: puedes especificar un poco?

Comment: Esto: `Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, fileProviderAuthority, photoFile);` me daba null. Y mas errores durante la ejecución, ya no los recuerdo. estoy probando otros códigos